# Ms Excel: How to parse / parsing data values from one cell to other 3 cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, export-to-excel

I have 4 cells. A11, A15, B11 and B15

I want to change the value from cell A11, and after that all other 3 cells to get the value from A11. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: In cells A15, B11 and B15 type `=A11`, so when you **manually** change the value of A11, all other 3 cells will have same value at A11

Comment: super, please write it as an answer, please @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cells A15, B11 and B15 type =A11,

so when you manually change the value of A11, all other 3 cells will have same value at A11

---

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns